# React Admin Change field based on related record field

Tags: react-admin

Let's say I have a record called 'assets' which has a column called deducitble. An asset can have one Insurer. The insurer has a boolean field 'allowOtherDeductible'.

When editing the asset, I want the ability to first check if the associated insurer has allowOtherDeductible set to true. If so I'll allow a TextInput for **deductible**, if false, a SelectInput.

How can I achieve this? I cannot see a way to fetch related record's fields when conditionally rendering fields.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pulling in all the insurers and loading the asset when the component loaded. Seems a bit inefficient, but I couldn't come up with a better way:

```js
export const AssetEdit = props => {
  const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
  const [insurers, setInsurers] = useState([]);
  const [asset, setAsset] = useState(null);
  const [otherDeductible, setOtherDeductible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    dataProvider.getOne('assets', { id: props.id })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      setAsset(data);
      return dataProvider.getList('insurers', { pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 100 } });
    })
    .then(({ data }) => setInsurers(data))
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (asset && insurers) {
      const selectedInsurer = insurers.find(insurer => insurer.id === asset?.insurer_id);
      setOtherDeductible(selectedInsurer?.other_deductible);
    }
  }, [insurers])

return (
    <Edit {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        {otherDeductible &&
        <NumberInput
          source={'deductible'}
          parse={val => dollarsToCents(val)}
          format={val => centsToDollars(val)}
        />
        }

        <FormDataConsumer>
          {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
            if(!otherDeductible){
              return <SelectInput
                source="deductible"
                parse={val => dollarsToCents(val)}
                format={val => centsToDollars(val)}
                choices={getDeductibleChoices(formData.insured_value)}
              />
            }
          }}
        </FormDataConsumer>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a custom Input taking advantage of the fact that `SimpleForm` injects the `record` to all its children:

```
const DeductibleInput = ({ record }) => {
    if (!record) return null;
    const { data, loaded } = useGetOne('insurers', record.insured_id);
    if (!loaded) return null; // or a loader component
    return data.otherDeductible 
      ? <NumberInput
          source="deductible"
          parse={val => dollarsToCents(val)}
          format={val => centsToDollars(val)}
        />
      : <SelectInput
          source="deductible"
          parse={val => dollarsToCents(val)}
          format={val => centsToDollars(val)}
          choices={getDeductibleChoices(record.insured_value)}
         />
}
```